# Soundcloud not abandoning audio focus

Tags: android, soundcloud

It seems like Soundcloud is not abandoning audio focus on pause. I have tested my own music streaming app against others like Bandcamp, which abandon focus on pause, but Soundcloud does not. Is this intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a known bug in Soundcloud app. They need to handle the audio focus changes for the optimum behaviour.